# Netbeans "Not yet implemented" when connected to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, netbeans

This is my school project i am getting a error "not yet implemented" when i try to insert.
i have created MYSQL databases and tables for this.
Removed some due to limit 
I have the problem in Insert and Update area

```
    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * Student_managment_system.java
 *
 * Created on 23-Nov-2015, 07:57:12
 */

package holidayhomework1;


import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Student
 */
public class Student_managment_system extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form Student_managment_system */
    public Student_managment_system() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jFrame1 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel14 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel15 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jtf1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jtf2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jtf3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jtf4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jtf5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jFrame2 = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tf1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        tf2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        tf3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        tf4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        tf5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        tf6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        tf7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        tf8 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel10.setText("Fees Management System");

        jLabel11.setText("Student ID");

        jLabel12.setText("Student Name");

        jLabel13.setText("Fees Amount");

        jLabel14.setText("Balance");

        jLabel15.setText("Last Paid");

        jButton6.setText("Search");
        jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton7.setText("Update");
        jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton8.setText("Delete");
        jButton8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton8ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton9.setText("Insert");
        jButton9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton9ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame1.getContentPane());
        jFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame1Layout);
        jFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(61, 61, 61)
                        .addComponent(jButton6)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButton7)
                        .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                        .addComponent(jButton8)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jButton9))
                    .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel11)
                                .addGap(246, 246, 246)
                                .addComponent(jtf1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 73, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel12)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel13)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel14)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel15))
                                .addGap(230, 230, 230)
                                .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(jtf4)
                                    .addComponent(jtf3)
                                    .addComponent(jtf2)
                                    .addComponent(jtf5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 73, Short.MAX_VALUE)))))
                    .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(62, 62, 62)
                        .addComponent(jLabel10)))
                .addContainerGap(28, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel10)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel11)
                    .addComponent(jtf1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel12)
                    .addComponent(jtf2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel13)
                    .addComponent(jtf3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel14)
                    .addComponent(jtf4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel15)
                    .addComponent(jtf5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton6)
                    .addComponent(jButton7)
                    .addComponent(jButton8)
                    .addComponent(jButton9))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jFrame2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jFrame2.getContentPane());
        jFrame2.getContentPane().setLayout(jFrame2Layout);
        jFrame2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jFrame2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Student ID");

        jLabel2.setText("Student Name");

        jLabel3.setText("Father Name");

        jLabel4.setText("Mobile Number");

        jLabel5.setText("Age");

        jLabel6.setText("Nationality");

        jLabel7.setText("Cast");

        jLabel8.setText("Gender");

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Ubuntu", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setText("School Management System");

        jButton1.setText("Insert");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Update");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Delete");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("Search");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setText("Fees Information");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(95, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 359, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(62, 62, 62))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(54, 54, 54)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1)
                        .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                        .addComponent(jButton2)
                        .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                        .addComponent(jButton3)
                        .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                        .addComponent(jButton4)
                        .addGap(74, 74, 74))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                            .addComponent(jLabel7)
                            .addComponent(jLabel8)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 58, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(128, 128, 128)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(tf5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 117, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(tf1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 117, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(tf2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 117, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(tf3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 117, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(tf4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 117, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(tf6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 117, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(tf7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 117, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(tf8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 117, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGap(147, 147, 147))))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(170, 170, 170)
                .addComponent(jButton5)
                .addContainerGap(231, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(tf1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(tf2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(tf3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(tf4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(tf5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(tf6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                    .addComponent(tf7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                    .addComponent(tf8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addComponent(jButton4)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton5)
                .addContainerGap(33, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
 String SID = tf1.getText();
String Name = tf2.getText();
String Fname = tf3.getText();
String Numb = tf4.getText();
String Age = tf5.getText();
String Nation = tf6.getText();
String Cast =tf7.getText();
String Gender = tf8.getText();

try
{
    Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
    Connection con = (Connection)
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentmanagement","root","root");
    Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    String query="Insert into Studentdetails values('"+SID+"','"+Name+"','"+Fname+"','"+Numb+"','"+Age+"','"+Nation+"','"+Cast+"','"+Gender+"');";
    Stmt.executeUpdate(query);

}
catch (Exception e)
        {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
}

        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
 String SID = tf1.getText();
String Name = tf2.getText();
String Fname = tf3.getText();
String Numb = tf4.getText();
String Age = tf5.getText();
String Nation = tf6.getText();
String Cast =tf7.getText();
String Gender = tf8.getText();
try
{
    Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
    Connection con = (Connection)
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/harman","root","gaes");
    Statement stmt=(Statement)con.createStatement();
    String query="Update StudentDetails Set SName='"+Name+"',FName='"+Fname+"',Number='"+Numb+"',Age='"+Age+"',Nationality='"+Nation+"',Cast='"+Cast+"',Gender='"+Gender+"' where SID='"+SID+"';";
          stmt.executeUpdate(query);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
}
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
String SID = tf1.getText();
try
{
    Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
    Connection con = (Connection)
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/harman","root","gaes");
    Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    String query="Delete from StudentDetails where SID = '"+SID+"';";
    Stmt.executeUpdate(query);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
}
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        jFrame1.setVisible(true);        // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        String SID = tf1.getText();
if (SID.isEmpty())
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"No StudentID Detected !!!!");
}
else
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
        Connection con = (Connection)
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdetails","root","root");
        Statement stmt = (Statement)
                con.createStatement();
        String query = "Select * from StudentDetails where SID = '"+SID+"';";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        if (rs.next())
        {
            String Name = rs.getString("SName");
            String Fname = rs.getString("FName");
            String Num = rs.getString("Number");
            String Age = rs.getString("Age");
            String Nat = rs.getString("Nationality");
            String cast = rs.getString("Cast");
            String Gender = rs.getString("Gender");
            //Critical Zone
            tf2.setText(Name);
            tf3.setText(Fname);
            tf4.setText(Num);
            tf5.setText(Age);
            tf6.setText(Nat);
            tf7.setText(cast);
            tf8.setText(Gender);


        }
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this ,"NO SUCH STUDENT EXIST!!!!");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
}// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

    private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
String SID = jtf1.getText();
if (SID.isEmpty())
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"No StudentID Detected !!!!");
}
else
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
        Connection con = (Connection)
                DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/harman","root","gaes");
        Statement stmt = (Statement)
                con.createStatement();
        String query = "Select * from feesinfo where SID = '"+SID+"';";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        if (rs.next())
        {
            String SName = rs.getString("SName");
            String Famount = rs.getString("Famount");
            String balance = rs.getString("Balance");
            String lastpaid = rs.getString("lastpaid");

            //Critical Zone
            jtf2.setText(SName);
            jtf3.setText(Famount);
            jtf4.setText(balance);
            jtf5.setText(lastpaid);



        }
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this ,"NO SUCH STUDENT EXIST!!!!");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
}
    }                                        

    private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     String SID = jtf1.getText();
String SName = jtf2.getText();
String Famount = jtf3.getText();
String Bal = jtf4.getText();
String lastpaid = jtf5.getText();
try
{
    Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
    Connection con = (Connection)
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/harman","root","gaes");
    Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    String query="Insert into feesinfo values ('"+SID+"','"+SName+"','"+Famount+"','"+Bal+"','"+lastpaid+"');";
    Stmt.executeUpdate(query);

}
catch (Exception e)
        {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
}// TODO add your handling code here:   // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      String SID = jtf1.getText();
String SName = jtf2.getText();
String Famount = jtf3.getText();
String Bal = jtf4.getText();
String lastpaid = jtf5.getText();  
try
{
    Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
    Connection con = (Connection)
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/harman","root","gaes");
    Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    String query="Update StudentDetails Set SName='"+SName+"',Famount='"+Famount+"',balance='"+Bal+"',lastpaid='"+lastpaid+"' where SID='"+SID+"';";
          stmt.executeUpdate(query);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
}// TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
String SID = jtf1.getText();
try
{
    Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
    Connection con = (Connection)
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/harman","root","gaes");
    Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
    String query="Delete from feesinfo where SID = '"+SID+"';";
    Stmt.executeUpdate(query);

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
}        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Student_managment_system().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to have an error here. you probably need to post the whole java file to check

Comment: added but removed some due to limit

Comment: is your message appears in an Dialog or in netbeans console?

Comment: it appears in a Dialog "JOptionPane"

Comment: in button1 you have Stmt.executeUpdate(query);   change it to stmt.execute(query) , lower case can make the difference

Comment: Thank you sir :D now it is working